# Number is out of range error in Delphi XE

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6, paradox

I'm using an old Paradox database along with an older Delphi program I inherited and it keeps giving me a Number is out of range error when I hit this statement:

```
POE_Data.OrdersTaxRate.AsFloat:= StrToFloat(Copy(TaxRateLabel.Caption, 1,1));
```

The `TaxRateLabel.Caption` equals 7%, and so the `StrToFloat` is passing just the 7 character.  The TaxRate field is defined in the database as a BCD field with 2 decimal places.  I don't see any minimum or maximum values set in the database, so why is this producing the number out of range error?

Comment: Which type of the OrdersTaxRate field in the DB? For example, with Postgres it is impossible to assign value larger then 0.99 to the filed with type `numeric(2,2)` just because (as i remember) first parameter in the type declaration is a total number (including precision) of the digits for values.

Comment: The OrdersTaxRate is a BCD field with 2 decimal places.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not familiar with Paradox (actually I forgot almost all about them). So, it is not answer but just hint: try those two code snippets: `POE_Data.OrdersTaxRate.AsFloat := 0.1;` and `POE_Data.OrdersTaxRate.AsFloat := 1.0;` If first will work and second will not - you have some troubles with data type.

Comment: And another hint: try to use `POE_Data.OrdersTaxRate.Value` instead of `POE_Data.OrdersTaxRate.AsFloat`

Comment: I tried all the suggestions above, but none of them worked.  I checked other records in the database and they seem to have a value of 7.00.

Comment: Have you tried using `AsBCD` yet? `POE_Data.OrdersTaxRate.AsBCD := StrToBcd(Copy(TaxRateLabel.Caption, 1,1));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Delphi XE there is a `AsBcd` property. You can use it together with StrToBcd function, which converts string to `TBcd`:

```
POE_Data.OrdersTaxRate.AsBcd:= StrToBcd(Copy(TaxRateLabel.Caption, 1,1));
```

Comment: I get a Undeclared identifier: 'StrToBcd' error when I use the line above.  Do I need to include something in the Uses section?

Comment: I think it's `FMTBcd`. Did you check the help?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when updating an old C++Builder project. The solution is to copy the Source\data\Data.DB.pas file to your project's code folder and then make the following code change:

```
procedure TBCDField.SetAsCurrency(Value: Currency);
begin
  if FCheckRange and ((Value < FMinValue) or (Value > FMaxValue)) then
    RangeError(Value, FMinValue, FMaxValue);
//  if FIOBuffer <> nil then
//    TDBBitConverter.UnsafeFrom<System.Currency>(Value, FIOBuffer);
//  SetData(FIOBuffer, False);
  SetData(@Value, False);    // replaces the lines above
end;                         // so can TField.AsBCD
```

Then add the modified Data.DB.pas file to your project & rebuild your project.